# How to delete Exchange meeting using EWS and notify attendees (how to obtain correct id of the meeting)

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

If I create a meeting using EWS I get ID which I can use to delete or update it later. It works well and sends all the notifications to the attendees.

However, if I get ID from FindItems request, it returns a different ID. This new ID  works in a different way. I can update and delete items, but nobody gets notified. SendMeetingInvitations is set to CalendarItemCreateOrDeleteOperationType.SendToAllAndSaveCopy, but it doesn't help.

I tried both EWS Managed API and EWS. Both work the same.

Unfortunately I can't save the first ID in some system, because some meetings I need to manage are created from Outlook.

Any ideas how can I obtain the correct ID or how can I make Exchange send notification on updated automatically in my case?

This is how I get the incorrect ID:

```
FolderIdType folderId = GetCalendarFolderId(meetingRoomEmail);
FindItemType findItemType = new FindItemType();
findItemType.ParentFolderIds = new BaseFolderIdType[] {folderId};
findItemType.ItemShape = new ItemResponseShapeType();
findItemType.ItemShape.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.IdOnly;

ArrayOfRealItemsType arrayOfRealItemsType =
            (ArrayOfRealItemsType) ((FindItemResponseMessageType) responseMessage).RootFolder.Item;
ItemType[] itemIdsOnly = arrayOfRealItemsType.Items;
```

**Update1**: it seems the issue is related to the fact that I'm looking in the resource (meeting room) calendar folder and the root item is in organizer's calendar folder. If my guess is correct, please, let me know how can I find the related item in Organizer's folder by the item in meeting room's folder.

PS: Exchange 2010 SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, your update makes sense. You need to update the organizer's copy so that everyone gets notified. You should be able to match them up using the `ICalUid` property.